# ReactJS remove one td from array when using array.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

We are building a web app that will process files from an FTP client. Currently, we have a mock "file" that we are working off of.

I have one component (please correct me if my terminology is wrong) that builds up the layout of a table and looks like.

```
render() {
    return (
                <tr>
                    <td>{this.fileData.dataTypeString}</td>
                    <td>{dateFormat(this.fileData.creationDate, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM tt")}</td>
                    <td>{this.fileData.value}</td>
                    <td >{this.fileData.origin}</td>
                    <td>{<a href=''><strong> Delete </strong></a>}</td>
                </tr>
```

This is then called from another component using the array.map for something like

```
<tbody>
                    {array.map(data =>
                        <SupportSummaryDataRow key={data.fileid} fileData={data} />)} 
                </tbody>
```

So my problem is this. The delete link (that goes nowhere yet yes) only needs to be present on one of the components. I would like to use the SupportSummaryDataRow component to load the array for 3 different components though.. There is one that I only need 2 elements from the backing component and to do so I took the incoming array and passed it through another array, filtering it down to only pull out the 2 items I need. Then in the array.map, I just used the "new" array.. which worked.

However, the delete is now persisting in all of them. I believe it's because it isn't being read from the file. But how do I hide it or remove it where I don't need it?

I have read options on using CSS to handle isHidden and such and can go that route if need be. But if there is a better way I would like to learn it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the delete link conditionally as well:

Step 1: Figure out whether you should render delete link or not. This can be based on data or each of the parent component can just set it to true/false if they know whether to render it or not.

```
const shouldRenderDelete = ... // some logic to figure out true/false
```

Step 2: Pass this flag to `SupportSummaryDataRow`

```
<SupportSummaryDataRow key={data.fileid} fileData={data} shouldRenderDelete={shouldRenderDelete} />
```

Step 3: Make delete rendering conditional based on `shouldRenderDelete`

```
<tr>
    <td>{this.fileData.dataTypeString}</td>
    <td>{dateFormat(this.fileData.creationDate, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM tt")}</td>
    <td>{this.fileData.value}</td>
    <td >{this.fileData.origin}</td>
    <td>{shouldRenderDelete && (<a href=''><strong> Delete </strong></a>)}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I was able to use something similar to this to make it work, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I am interpreting your question correctly. In my case I will add another prop called "delete"

```
const array = [{fieldid: 1, delete: true}, {fieldid: 2, delete: false}, {fieldid: 3, delete: false}];

<tbody>
                {array.map(data =>
                    <SupportSummaryDataRow key={data.fileid} fileData={data} delete={data.delete}/>)} 
            </tbody>
```

And in your child component SupportSummaryDataRow using the && operator:

```
render() {
return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.fileData.dataTypeString}</td>
                <td>{dateFormat(this.fileData.creationDate, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM tt")}</td>
                <td>{this.fileData.value}</td>
                <td >{this.fileData.origin}</td>
                {this.props.delete && (
                <td>{<a href=''><strong> Delete </strong></a>}</td>
                )}

            </tr>
        )}
```